# Java BigDecimal / Double precision error

Tags: java, double, bigdecimal

I'm trying to simulate the ATM amount input in Java, ie. say the user keeps inputting "1", the amount shown should be:

```
0.00
0.01
0.11
1.11
11.11
111.11
```

I tried both Double and BigDecimal for processing:

```
println( ((new BigDecimal(current)).multiply(new BigDecimal(10)).add(new BigDecimal(0.01))).setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP).toString()) )

println( "" + Double.parseString(current) * 10 + 0.01 )
```

However both seems to show this instead:

```
0.00
0.01
0.11
1.11
11.1 <<< missing the 0.01 at the end
111.01
```

are they both due to a precision rounding error (I thought BigDecimal does not have this problem) or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is floating point math broken?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: IMHO, you should never use BigDecimals or Doubles for currency. If you want the most accuracy convert to pennies. And work with those directly.

Comment: Your code looks okay, but the order of operations on your `println` line might be messing things up. What happens if you move `+ ""` to the end?

Comment: Agree that Doubles should never be used for currencies but BigDecimals can be used - in accountancy systems where you need control over the rounding and sometimes need fractions of a penny/cent they are the best option.

Comment: @DaveMorrissey, Doubles will work just fine...  as long as you work in pennies (or whatever the quantum of _your_ currency is called.)  If both operands are integer-valued doubles, and the result fits in 51 bits or less, then +, -, and * will all give exact results.

Comment: If you're working in pennies you can use `int`. `BigDecimal` gives you extra flexibility in accountancy and tax calculations.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest option might be to record the input as a String. After each key press append the new character to the end of it, and format the number by creating a BigDecimal and dividing it by 100.

```
String input = "111111";
BigDecimal value = new BigDecimal(input).divide(new BigDecimal(100)); // 1111.11
```

That said, I've just tried your code in a loop and it appears to work fine. You'll need to post the code showing how you generate `current`.

```
String current = "0.00";
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    current = (new BigDecimal(current).multiply(new BigDecimal(10)).add(new BigDecimal(0.01))).setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP).toString();
    System.out.println(current);
}

//    0.01
//    0.11
//    1.11
//    11.11
//    111.11
//    1111.11
//    11111.11
//    111111.11
//    1111111.11
//    11111111.11
```

Answer (score 1):

Java BigDecimal has a constructor that takes a double and another that takes a string. You are using the double constructor, although the string constructor is usually recommended. Have you tried it?

`BigDecimal addend = new BigDecimal("0.01");`

For more information, see [The Evil Big Decimal Constructor](http://rayfd.me/2007/04/26/the-evil-bigdecimal-constructor/).

Answer (score 0):

It's easier to mess with the string:

```
public void test() {
    String s = "0.00";
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        s = new BigDecimal(s.replaceAll(Pattern.quote("."), "") + "1").divide(ONEHUNDRED).toString();
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

Here I remove the ".", add a "1", create a `BigDecimal` from it and divide that by 100.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to compute an amount on the fly? Just store the string as it comes and parse it at the end.

```
// Store user input as string (pseudo code)
String readUserInput() {
  String accumulator = "";
  while (user input available) {
    accumulator += user input;
  }
  return accumulator;
}

// Get user input as double
Double getAmount(String input) {
  return Double.parseDouble( input ) / 100.0;
}

// Or a BigDecimal too
BigDecimal getAmount(String input) {
  return new BigDecimal(input).divide(new BigDecimal(100));
}
```